# problem with pspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, pspice

I am not familiar with Pspice and I want to simulate RC circuit in that but my circuit does not work properly(like in the paper analysis)[image: this image is my circuit]

[image: and this is my simulation screen]

Comment: What do you mean by, "my circuit does not work properly"? Please specify. Are you not reaching a targeted voltage or current? Were you expecting different behavior? Tell us what you think went wrong.

Comment: as I wrote in parenthesis, with paper analysis the time constant is 0.000001 seconds but in the simulation screen this is not.

Comment: @KingDuken
actually, an image that shows the simulation is not explicit, but be sure that is wrong with time constant (I checked that in that large time scaling).

Comment: You have an RC circuit with R=10k, C=1n or equivalently R=10e3, C=1e-9. Time constant is given by RC = 10e3*1e-9 = 1e-5 or 0.00001 so you're off by a factor of 10. Also note that the applied voltage doesn't change the time constant, though you might find analysis easier with a 1V input.

Comment: The x-axis of your graph is in seconds not micro-seconds, zoom in.  Roff of your switch is likely 1MegOhm

Comment: thanks, friends.
my problem becomes solved with your guides.